# How to make WordPress plugin to show content on all admin pages?

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I am trying to develop a plugin so that it could display a content like a small notification banner throughout all admin pages in WordPress. I just need to know they functional way and I could develop its design. I'm sorry to ask a questions without any code implementation but I tried my best to get some idea on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress has some glorious things called [Action Hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference), some of which fire on the admin page. Basically they're called in order all the time, so you can say "Hey WordPress, run X function on Y hook", and any where/any time that Y hook runs, X function will be triggered.

They have a handy one called [`admin_notices`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) that you can drop notices into (similar to the "Post Updated" notices when you publish/update a page or post)

So first you write a function that echos a notice (note that currently you need to include the HTML markup for them)

```
function so51734745_admin_notice() { ?>
    <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
        <p><?php _e( 'My Plugin is Doing Something!', 'plugin-text-domain' ); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Now you just hook it into the `admin_notices` hook:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'so51734745_admin_notice' );
```

> Note: It's generally considered a bad practice to have a persistent non-dismissable notices when your plugin is active. There are many plugins (I'll keep nameless) that have persistent notices until you complete X action. Unless it's **critical**, notices should be dismissable and or only fired under certain conditions.

With that note in mind, one of my plugins alerts users when they're using my plugin to override page/post content similar to this:

```
function so51734745_admin_notice() {
    if( $my_condition == true ){ ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p><?php _e( 'My Plugin is Doing Something!', 'plugin-text-domain' ); ?></p>
        </div>
    }
<?php }
```

So it only fires while that condition is true. Keep that in mind if your plugin has a broad spectrum appeal. If every plugin is "important" with a "persistent notice", then no plugin is important and all notices are ignored.

If you need a different type of banner you can consider similar HTML output on another admin hook like [`admin_footer`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_footer), but then you'll have to style it yourself with a CSS file that's properly enqueued via [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts).

Also note that the current iteration of Gutenberg (lamely) just hides admin notices on Gutenberg enabled page/post edit screens - so you'll need to work around that if that's an issue for you.

Comment: What is the alternative to notices ? Let's say for example i need to display a div on all plugin pages (custom post type list, settings page, single cpt etc ) .

Comment: @IonT - The latter part of that, using something like the `admin_footer` hook? Then you can drop whatever you want in there and show it based on whatever condition you want, like checking the current URL, or what screen is being used with `get_current_screen()`, etc

Comment: I already tried the ```admin_footer``` hook, it displays the output at the bottom of the desired page. 

Instead i am trying to display a block of code that behaves as a header for all the pages related to my plugin. 

Wordpress by default outputs ```<div id="wpcontent">``` on admin pages and i want to display my content as a child to this div. I know i could use ```admin_footer``` and then with JS to append it to ```<div id="wpcontent">``` but i wonder if there is a "cleaner" solution.

Comment: All the default available hooks are here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request. I don't recall off the top of my head if any go directly in `#wpcontent` or not unfortunately. If not you will likely need to use some JS to move it around, but there may be an otherwise acceptable action hook as well!